# Kubernetes/Helm: any examples with ConfigMap and "binaryData:"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

With Kubernetes 1.10.* we can use `binaryData:` with `ConfigMap` and I am trying to combine it with `Helm`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: some_config_map
data:
  text_data: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "truststores/simple_text_file.txt" }}
binaryData:
  trustore.jks: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "truststores/trustore.jks" | b64enc }}
```

I am not sure about the last line - regardless of syntax:

```
 {{ "truststores/trustore.jks" | b64enc }}
 {{ "truststores/trustore.jks" }}
```

the `trustore.jks` is empty when I deploy it.

So how can I use `binaryData:` ?

Comment: You need to remove `|-` for binary data.

Comment: so what is answer? can you accept answer or post the answer?!?

Answer (score 17):

Your syntax looks fine and everything should work properly. Files in the field  `binaryData` must be encoded with base64, so, `{{ .Files.Get "truststores/trustore.jks" | b64enc }}` is correct.

Try to apply the configuration with debug key and investigate what went wrong, possibly there is no such file or there are some problems with encoding.

Comment: Shouldn't it use `.Files.GetBytes`?

Comment: No `.Files.GetBytes` should not be used. It even throws an error. The Code from the Question is right, and works great for my k8s installation.

Comment: @kirrmann Then what is a typical use-case for `.Files.GetBytes`?

Answer (score 9):

This might be too late, but maybe it will help someone.

You need to add indentation to your base64 encoded string.

```
{{ .Files.Get "truststores/trustore.jks" | b64enc | indent 4}}
```

This is also applies to your text file:

```
{{ .Files.Get "truststores/simple_text_file.txt" | indent 4}}
```

This should add 4 spaces to each line from the file

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is good but as defined here https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files .Files don't load file from anywhere. So "truststores/trustore.jks" if truststores is not part of your chart folder